# How can I get the installed composer packages programatically?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there any way to get all composer packages and their version using PHP or do I need to parse them from its `composer.json`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need to do that ?

Comment: I'm trying to add content to my views depending on whether a package exists or not by using their data.

Comment: Please share more details - what **exactly** are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Composer's API to get this.

Just do:

```php
$installed = \Composer\InstalledVersions::getRawData();
```

Which will get you an array with all the installed packages and their versions.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to get composer.json data from a specific package? Thanks!